# Is there a Planning Poker or similar app in Microsoft Teams

Tags: ms-office, microsoft-teams

Is there a planning poker (Scrum Planning Poker) or similar app extension in Microsoft Teams.

Comment: I created [https://www.planfree.dev](https://www.planfree.dev/#/) which is completely free and open source. I was sick of website's badgering you to sign up for premium to continue playing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an app: Team O'clock. I have a team working on an application in the future.

Comment: I logged in to system and clicked the "Add to Microsoft Teams" button, but it didn't work. Seems like it's still under development. when it will be available ?

Comment: You can add via Apps in Microsoft Teams application.

Comment: Added Team O'Clock to MS Teams. But Connect button does not do anything.

Comment: [$30/mo for 20 members, $70/mo for 50 members, "contact us" for more](https://www.teamoclock.com/more-about/planning-poker)

Answer (score 14):

You could also try this one: https://planningpokeronline.com/

It doesnt have integration but works really well and its so simple

Comment: Very nice... so simple, as you say it

Comment: I am the creator btw :) Feel free to ask me anything

Answer (score 4):

Since it is not mentioned here:
[ScrumPoker integrated in MS Teams](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA200001850)

Comment: This is the only one I can find as of November 2022

Answer (score 1):

This app is not for MS Teams but I've been using it since it has a really cool feature to keep track of sprint points during planning.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.btreeapps.scrumpoker&hl=en

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

On https://estimationpoker.de there is a free version of planning poker which is easy to use.